# Why do I need to click two times to trigger an .onclick function?

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple script, that after clicking a span changes the opacity of another element.
But for some reason, I have to click it two times.
I heard it could be something with whitespace, but I still cannot solve it.

Here's the element:

```
<div class="popup">
  <span class="popup__close" onclick="hidePopup()"><i class="fas fa-lg fa-times"></i></span>
  <h3 class="popup__heading">
    Check our newsletter!
  </h3>
  <p class="popup__text u-margin-bottom-xs">
    Register to our newsletter to see the newest offers!
  </p>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn--small btn--rounded">Register</a>
</div>
```

And here's the script:

```
<script>
  function hidePopup() {
    const close = document.querySelector('.popup__close');
    const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
    close.addEventListener('click', function() {
      popup.style.opacity = '0';
    })
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The reason you have to click twice is that you're only adding the eventListener on the span once the user clicks on it the first time. Then you have to click it again to do what you want. Just set the opacity in `hidePopup()` and don't add another eventListener there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double click as you are attaching event handler using `addEventListener()` in the inline click handler.

I would recommend you to use [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event and soley attach event handler using `addEventListener()`

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');

    const close = document.querySelector('.popup__close');
    const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
    close.addEventListener('click', function() {
        popup.style.opacity = '0';
    });
});
```

And there is no need for ugly inline click handler and the function `hidePopup()`, remove them

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extraneous call to addEventListener and simply hide the element in the click event handler.

```
function hidePopup() {
 const close = document.querySelector('.popup__close');
 const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
 popup.style.opacity = '0';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the function hidePopup, notice that you "addEventListener" when the function runs 1st time,

when you addEventListener, doesn't make the function run!
you assign the listener so that later if clicked, then it will run the function you assigned in the Listener.

if you use addEventListener, you dont need to use onClick attribute to call the function anymore...

---

I see that your goal is to hide the content when close button is clicked, by following your code, there are 2 ways for that:

**1st way**

> 

```js
//you only need to select once
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
 
function hidePopup() {
 popup.style.opacity = '0';
}

//additional function if you want to show pop up
function showPopup() {
 popup.style.opacity = '1';
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">

<span class="popup__close" onclick="hidePopup()">
<i class="fas fa-lg fa-times">X</i>
</span>


<h3 class="popup__heading">
  Check our newsletter!
</h3>

<p class="popup__text u-margin-bottom-xs">
  Register to our newsletter to see the newest offers!
</p>

<a href="#" class="btn btn--small btn--rounded">Register</a>

</div>


<Br><Br><br>

<span class="popup__show" onclick="showPopup()">
click me to show pop up
</span>
```

**2nd Way**

```js
//select both button and Popup

const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
const close = document.querySelector('.popup__close');
  
close.addEventListener('click', function() {
    popup.style.opacity = '0';
});
  

const show = document.querySelector('.popup__show');
  
show.addEventListener('click', function() {
    popup.style.opacity = '1';
});
```

```html
<div class="popup">

<span class="popup__close">
<i class="fas fa-lg fa-times">X</i>
</span>


<h3 class="popup__heading"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63126988/why-do-i-need-to-click-two-times-to-trigger-an-onclick-function#>
  Check our newsletter!
</h3>


<p class="popup__text u-margin-bottom-xs">
  Register to our newsletter to see the newest offers!
</p>


<a href="#" class="btn btn--small btn--rounded">Register</a>

</div>


<span class="popup__show">Click here to show pop up</span>
```